# Remove every other comma and surround with brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates, gis

So using jquery and I have a string of coordinates like so:

```
38.313072,-89.863845,38.312675,-89.863586,38.310405,-89.862091,38.310405,-89.862091,38.309913,-89.861976,38.309768,-89.861976,38.309768,-89.861976
```

I need them to look like this:

```
[38.313072, -89.863845] [38.312675, -89.863586] [38.310405, -89.862091] [38.310405,-89.862091] [38.309913, -89.861976] [38.309768, -89.861976] [38.309768, -89.861976] [38.30965, -89.861991]
```

So I need to figure out how to replace every other comma with a space and bracket sets of coordinates.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex.

```
([-\d.]+),([-\d.]+),?
```

[**Regex Explanation and Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lH3vB7/3)

1. `[-\d.]`: Character class, `-` will match literal `-` hyphen, `\d` will match a single digit, `.` will match `.` literally. When mentioned inside class sequence doesn't matter.
2. `+`: Matches one or more occurrences of the previous matches
3. `(...)`: Capturing Group. The matches inside the braces are captured and returned in `$1`, `$2`, ...
4. `,?`: To not match the every other comma
5. `g`: Global Match. To match all possible occurrences.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zkn7gonw/)

```js
var str = '38.313072,-89.863845,38.312675,-89.863586,38.310405,-89.862091,38.310405,-89.862091,38.309913,-89.861976,38.309768,-89.861976,38.309768,-89.861976';

var result = str.replace(/([-\d.]+),([-\d.]+),?/g, '[$1, $2] ').trim();
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, 0, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Very close, but I don't need the commas between bracketed sets

Comment: @Tushar you see it can't be removed safely !

Comment: @Dean see my answer below ! how it fit exactly what you need !

Comment: @Tushar much better ! it was not so safely !

Comment: @Dean Welcome! Glad to help :)

Comment: @Tushar - Wait...  I do need that other comma.

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex !
It's perfect for this !

```js
var str = "38.313072,-89.863845,38.312675,-89.863586,38.310405,-89.862091,38.310405,-89.862091,38.309913,-89.861976,38.309768,-89.861976,38.309768,-89.861976,38.30965, -89.861991";

var expected = "[38.313072, -89.863845] [38.312675, -89.863586] [38.310405, -89.862091] [38.310405,-89.862091] [38.309913, -89.861976] [38.309768, -89.861976] [38.309768, -89.861976] [38.30965, -89.861991]"


var computed = str.replace(/(([0-9\-. ]*)(,)([0-9\-. ]*)),?/g, '[$2 $3 $4] ');

document.write('computed<br>')
document.write(str.replace(/(([0-9\-. ]*)(,)([0-9\-. ]*)),?/g, '[$2 $3 $4] '))



document.write( "<hr>expected<br>" + expected  )
```

Comment: Suggestions: **1.** `-` don't need to be escaped when used as first/last character in the class `[]` **2.** No need of including space in the class as the input string doesn't contain space at all **3.**  `,?` can be removed safely

Comment: @Tushar `-` thanks i was not aware of that ! the space it's there only to prevent some 'accident' :-) ;

Comment: I read question again and I see `replace every other comma with a space and bracket sets of coordinates.`, so OP wants to replace alternate comma  by space, the input string doesn't contain the spaces, so the ` `-space from class can be removed.

Comment: Please read the question again, **compare the output of your code to what OP wants**

Comment: @Tushar i have modified my answer to be easy for you to see how **it fit perfectly** ! (i have added the expected and the computed result), like that you can compare :-)

Comment: You can still remove the space from character class, `[0-9\-. ]` ==> `[0-9\-.]` +1

Comment: Yes i can, but it's preferable to keep it because we can match a human inputs which can contains 'space' !

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest to use `\s` instead of space

Comment: @Tushar yes ! also ! why not !

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty, but it works:

```
var coordinateString = "38.313072,-89.863845,38.312675,-89.863586,38.310405,-89.862091,38.310405,-89.862091,38.309913,-89.861976,38.309768,-89.861976,38.309768,-89.861976";

var coordinateArray = coordinateString.split(",");
var coordinateResult = "";
var i = 0;
while(i<coordinateArray.length){
  coordinateResult +="[" + coordinateArray[i] + ", " + coordinateArray[i+1] + "]";
  i += 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work.

```js
function toPairs(src){
  // Split the string into values.
  var values = src.split(',');
  
  // Group these values 2 by 2.
  var pairs = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i += 2){
    pairs.push("[" + values[i] + ", " + values[i + 1] + "]");
  }
  
  // Join with a whitespace.
  return pairs.join(" ");
}

document.body.innerHTML = toPairs("38.313072,-89.863845,38.312675,-89.863586,38.310405,-89.862091,38.310405,-89.862091,38.309913,-89.861976,38.309768,-89.861976,38.309768,-89.861976");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `while` loop , `Array.prototype.splice()` , returning results as array of arrays

```js
var str = "38.313072,-89.863845,38.312675,-89.863586,38.310405,-89.862091,38.310405,-89.862091,38.309913,-89.861976,38.309768,-89.861976,38.309768,-89.861976"
, res = []
, arr = str.split(",");
while (arr.length) res.push(arr.splice(0, 2))

console.log(res, JSON.stringify(res, null, 2))
```

Comment: You forgot to add `-`, minus sign in regex

Comment: @Tushar See updated post. Substituted `while` loop , `.splice()` for  `RegExp`